# Image picked from gallery is not getting set in image view

Tags: android, android-studio

I am making a button and image view and if I click the button I want to display 3 options choose pic from gallery, take photo and cancel. And after selecting the image it should replace the image view, but when I am picking the image from gallery it is not replacing the image view and when I am choosing take photo option my  application stops and gives the error:

> {FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/temp.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()"}

I am attaching my function which I am calling in the button onClickListener.

```js
// function to choose profile image
    private void selectImage() {

        final CharSequence[] options = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery","Cancel" };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(student_form.this);
        builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
        builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (options[item].equals("Take Photo"))
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                }
                else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery"))
                {
                    Intent intent = new   Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 2);

                }
                else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

    @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == 1) {
                File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
                for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
                    if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
                        f = temp;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap;
                    BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),
                            bitmapOptions);

                    imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                    String path = android.os.Environment
                            .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + File.separator
                            + "Phoenix" + File.separator + "default";
                    f.delete();
                    OutputStream outFile = null;
                    File file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
                    try {
                        outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, outFile);
                        outFile.flush();
                        outFile.close();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if (requestCode == 2) {

                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePath, null, null, null);
                c.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
                String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
                c.close();
                Bitmap thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
                Log.w("path of image from gallery......******************.........", picturePath+"");
                imageview.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please come up with one problem only. Reword and remove half of your code please. You can make another post for that.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the Solution for the question, now I am able to set the image to imageview by both camera and gallery, what I needed to do was add real-time permission for api23+,Change the code of selectImage() in above code.

```
private void selectImage() {

    final CharSequence[] options = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery","Cancel" };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(student_form.this);
    builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
    builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            if (options[item].equals("Take Photo"))
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
            else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery"))
            {

                Intent intent = new   Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 2);

            }
            else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}

@SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        }

        } else if (requestCode == 2) {



            String[] galleryPermissions = {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

            if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(this, galleryPermissions)) {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePath, null, null, null);
                c.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
                String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
                c.close();

                Bitmap thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
                imageview.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
            } else {
                EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(this, "Access for storage",
                        101, galleryPermissions);
            }


        }
    }
```

add the following code at the end just above the last curly bracket this is to check real time permission for camera

```
 public void EnableRuntimePermission(){
    final int RequestPermissionCode  = 1 ;

    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(student_form.this,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA))
    {

        Toast.makeText(student_form.this,"CAMERA permission allows us to Access CAMERA app", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } else {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(student_form.this,new String[]{
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, RequestPermissionCode);

    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int RC, String per[], int[] PResult) {

    final int RequestPermissionCode  = 1 ;
    switch (RC) {

        case RequestPermissionCode:

            if (PResult.length > 0 && PResult[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                Toast.makeText(student_form.this,"Permission Granted, Now your application can access CAMERA.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(student_form.this,"Permission Canceled, Now your application cannot access CAMERA.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            break;
    }
}
```

and also don't forget to call method EnableRuntimePermission(); at the start when initialising variables.

Comment: Huge answer. In my case, Rx swallowed the error, so it was hard to find out what was the exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check this example from Android:

https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

Basically you need to use a FileProvider now.

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            ...
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                                                  "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                                                  photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}
```

App Manifest

```
<application>
   ...
   <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.android.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
    ...
</application>
```

file_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.example.package.name/files/Pictures" />
</paths>
```

Comment: was mine an old method

Comment: You can follow the example from the link I posted. You can find all the code in there.

Comment: I appreciate that answerers don't want to do free work for a question author, but this answer is essentially "link only", and thus is at risk of deletion in the Review Queue. Can you expand on it somewhat? I will refrain from flagging for now, but expanding may help ensure that it is not flagged in the future.

Comment: can anyone of you explain what I am doing wrong and how to use fileprovider, I can't understand it